# AutoStart ASP.NET Application using AppFabric

Tags: asp.net, appfabric

I have hosted my ASP.NET website on Windows AppFabric. I am trying to use AutoStart feature of AppFabric to keep the site running.

I have configured all required settings and I can see in task manager that IIS worker process for my Application Pool is always running. As expected code is Global.asax is not executed till first request is made and first request takes long time.

I do have some bootstrapper code that I want to execute as soon as IIS worker process is started.

I tried defining AppInitialize static method in App_code which is called when application is started

```
namespace TestProject.ServiceHost.App_Code
{
    public class AppInitializer
    {
        public static void AppInitialize()
        {
            Bootstrapper.Instance.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

But this method is not fired when IIS worker process is started. Has anyone used this method successfully? Or is there any other better approach for executing code when application is started?

References I used:
http://blog.diniscruz.com/2013/01/aspnet-appcode-appinitialize-non.html
http://weblogs.asp.net/britchie/archive/2010/09/08/death-to-windows-services-long-live-appfabric.aspx

Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

If you have set AppPool recycling conditions, you can have warm up script to load initial configuration, dependencies etc.  This script can be added to scheduler, set its time after app pool is restarted(which will be at regular interval something like every night). 
Use tinyget.exe to browser your page or service so that you can load all the configuration/dependencies at the time of application startup.